# Elasticsearch 6 self referencing loop error

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do a bulk operation:

```
var response = await _client.BulkAsync(new BulkRequest
{
    Operations = list.Select(x => new BulkIndexOperation<T>(x)).Cast<IBulkOperation>().ToList(),
    Refresh = Elasticsearch.Net.Refresh.True
});
```

I get this referencing loop error:

> JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for
>   property 'parent' with type 'Category'. Path 'children[0]'.

I've seen solutions for this, and I think I'm close, but I am not sure where here to set ignore?

```
var connection = new ConnectionSettings(
                new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new System.Uri(settings.Value.ElasticSearchUrl)),
                new HttpConnection(), 
                new ConnectionSettings.SourceSerializerFactory((jsonSettings, nestSettings) => 
                    jsonSettings.?????)
            );
```

********UPDATE**************
I got it to work with this:

```
   var connection = new ConnectionSettings(
        new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new System.Uri(settings.Value.ElasticSearchUrl)),
        sourceSerializer: (builtin, setting) => new JsonNetSerializer(
            builtin, setting, () => new JsonSerializerSettings {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            }
        ));
```

Comment: `jsonSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

Comment: I tried that, but I don't know if I am referencing the correct libraries. I get "IElasticsearchSerializer does not contain a definition for ReferenceLoopHandling"